# Android gradle illegal rule

Tags: java, android, gradle

Im trying to run android studio project. It was not created by me.
But im getting an error so i cant event buld the project.
The cause is gradle scipt. I dont know what's wrong with project. because im sure it works fine.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.8.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
model {
    def signConf
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 20
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.minergate.miner"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }

    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "miner"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-exceptions")
         * ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
         * stl       = "system"
         */

        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        ldLibs.add("log")
        stl = "gnustl_static"
//        stl = "c++_static"
    }



    android.buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled = false
            signingConfig = signConf
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled = true
            //proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
            signingConfig = signConf
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        //create("arm") {
        //    ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        //}
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.miner
        }
        //create("arm8") {
        //    ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        //}
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        //create("x86-64") {
        //    ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        //}
        //create("mips") {
        //    ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        //}
        //create("mips-64") {
        //    ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        //}
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        //create("all")
    }

    android.signingConfigs {
        create("signRelease") {
            keyAlias = '**'
            keyPassword = '**'
            storeFile = file('KeyStore')
            storePassword = '**'
            signConf = it
        }
    }

    android.compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.+'
}
```

And im getting error:

```
Error:(3, 0) Cause: startup failed: build file '...\app\build.gradle': 3: illegal rule @ line 3, column 5. def signConf ^ 1 error
```

Comment: `model { def signConf`...  Where did you get this file?

Comment: what do you mean?)

Comment: Just read the error `illegal rule @ line 3, column 5. def signConf`.

Comment: I assume that is just some random variable set at `signConf = it`, so I again ask - where did you get this file, and can you ask those people how this works?

Comment: im not sure those who wrote it can help me)
and def just defines variable, doesnt it?

Comment: It does, yes. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_variable_definition But if you just want the code to run and don't need to sign it for release, you don't need it

Comment: If you are sure this code should run as-is, then make sure you are using the same version of Gradle as where you got this code.

Comment: ok, if def is not illegal, why gradle can take it so?

Comment: It could depend on your version of Gradle. Just because syntactically it is valid, does not mean execution-wise it is excepted

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cricket_007
removing variable  signConf from code did the trick.
Later ill try to change the gradle version to run code as-is.